# Find out PCM properties from saved byte stream

Tags: java, android, audio, pcm

I have a file that contains a stream of raw PCM bytes. Is there a way to find out the sampling rate and bit depth just from the file itself? Some kind of an analyzer or something like that; I would just like to avoid trying to guess properties by playing the stream with random settings.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming sane input, you can probably deduce bit depth / encoding by finding the possibility with the least high frequency noise.

Sample rate may be tricky, unless there is are noise components of expected frequency which could be detected (some research has been done on power line hum for example), or perhaps acoustical properties of a given recorder such as interference across the diameter of the microphone or of the casing which would shape the spectrum of the noise.  Many sources may also use a consistent hardware sampling rate and convert it when others are desired, a process that may leave artifacts.  But for a well done recording from unspecified hardware, it may indeed be challenging.

Another related challenge is distinguishing interleaved stereo from mono at twice the sample rate.  This gets tricky because at low frequencies you'd expect the same content in both channels, while at high you'd expect a phase difference.  But even in a mono track, you wouldn't expect low frequency components to be changing much between successive samples, while you would expect high frequency ones to do so.  One idea might be to look for delayed  (or advanced) correlation between possible left and right at high frequencies.  Another might be to see if the phase difference between successive low frequency components comprised two individual monotonically spaced interleaved sequences with an unrelated difference between the two (stereo) or a single evenly spaced monotonic sequence (mono).